# How to create a text slider using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slide

I want  to realize a text slider like this:

http://www.federica.unina.it/ingegneria/ingegneria-del-software-ingegneria/progettazione-qualita-software/

There are arrows that will bring you to the next or previous page. I notice that when you click to arrow, the page is same. How can I make that?

Comment: If they can do it, so can you. With code. When you have some, come back with a specific question, okay?

Comment: also... sometimes CTRL+U does a lot of magic...

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing that is creating multiple divs, make all display: none and use Javascript to control the buttons and show/hide divs based on where you are. For example, use the following javascript:

```
var page = 1;

$('#next').click( function() {
    $('#' + page).hide();
    page = page + 1;
    $('#' + page).show();
});

$('#previous').click( function() {
    $('#' + page).hide();
    page = page - 1;
    $('#' + page).show();
});
```

I created [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj5vyLac/) so you can see the effect. Basically I have 3 divs with different content, and I switch the content by hiding and displaying the divs depending on what 'page' you are on. This does require jQuery. Using [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/aj5vyLac/1/) that I made, you will not be able to navigate to not existing pages.